# How do I use GetOptions to get the default argument?

Tags: perl

I've read the doc for [`GetOptions`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) but I can't seem to find what I need... (maybe I am blind)

What I want to do is to parse command line like this

```
myperlscript.pl -mode [sth] [inputfile]
```

I can use the `-mode` part, but I am not sure how to get the [inputfile]. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't use `GetOptions` for this task. `GetOptions` will simply parse options for you and leave everything that is not an option in `@ARGV`. So after calling `GetOptions` simply look at `@ARGV` for any file names passed on the command line.

Answer (score 6):

Anything not handled by GetOptions is left in `@ARGV`.  So you would likely want something like

```
use Getopt::Long;
my %opt
my $inputfile = 'default';
GetOptions(\%opt, 'mode=s');
$inputfile = $ARGV[0] if defined $ARGV[0];
```

Answer (score 6):

`GetOptions` will leave any arguments that it didn't parse, in the `@ARGV` variable. So you can just loop over the `@ARGV` variable.

```
use Getopt::Long;
my %opt;
GetOptions(
  \%opt,
  'mode=s'
);

for my $filename (@ARGV){
  parse( $filename, \%opt );
}
```

There is another option, you can use the special `<>` argument callback option.

```
use Getopt::Long qw'permute';
our %opt;
GetOptions(
  \%opt,
  'mode=s',
  '<>' => sub{
    my($filename) = @_;
    parse( $filename, \%opt );
  }
);
```

This is useful if you want to be able to work on multiple files, but use different options for some of them.

```
perl test.pl -mode s file1 file2 -mode t file3
```

This example will set `$opt{mode}` to `s`, then it will call `parse` with `file1` as an argument. Then it will call `parse` with `file2` as the argument. It will then change `$opt{mode}` to `t`, and call `parse` with `file3`, as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

The command line arguments that don't begin with `-` will still be in `@ARGV`, won't they?